# NgModule, BrowserModule and others isn't known in files

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add a module as below (from angular.io) but nothing is known in my file which is named as `app.module.ts` except AppComponent in my angular2 app.

```
    import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

    @NgModule({
      imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
      declarations: [ AppComponent ],
      bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Also I need to import `import { Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';` or other imports from angular.io but I cannot do it in no way! Visual Studio code underlines my imports. What can I do? I tried to remove and npm install again but didn't worked.

Comment: make sure to install your libraries : `npm install`

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine I'm sure that is installed

Comment: try to use `@angular/cli` to create your project https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine I'm always working on a project but it hasn't app.module.ts file, that's why I'm trying to create it.

Comment: can you show more code and the structure of your app

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine It's completely working and I can edit it, but, I'm sorry, I can't share with you.